# Dynamic button placement issue in a Swing application

Tags: java, swing

My Aim is that when i click button b1("SHOW"),button b2("BUTTON 2") should appear at 10px to the right of button b1.When i'm clicking button b1 for the 1st time,it works as intended but from second times the button b2 is getting placed at (0,0) position.why?

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Spring;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DynamicSpring implements ActionListener
{
  JPanel jp;
  JFrame jf;
  JButton b1,b2;
  SpringLayout sl;
  DynamicSpring()
  {
     jf=new JFrame("DynamicSpring");
     jf.setSize(500,500);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     sl=new SpringLayout();
     jp=new JPanel(sl);

     b1=new JButton("SHOW");
     b1.setSize(100,100);
     sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,b1,10,SpringLayout.WEST,jp);     
      sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,b1,10,SpringLayout.NORTH,jp);  
     b1.addActionListener(this);
     jp.add(b1); 

     b2=new JButton("Button 2");
     b2.setSize(100,100);


    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    jf.setVisible(true);



  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
      sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,b2,10,SpringLayout.EAST,b1);
      jp.add(b2);

      jp.repaint();
       jp.validate();
  }

  public static void main(String... s)
  {
     new DynamicSpring();
  }

}
```

Comment: Remove the second question. it's off topic anyway.

Comment: Call `revalidate` followed by `repaint`

Comment: still getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MigLayout](http://miglayout.com/) instead of SpringLayout.
With MigLayout you can use the *hidemode* constraints:

*hidemode  : Sets the hide mode for the component. If the hide mode has been specified in the This hide mode can be overridden by the component constraint. The hide mode specified how the layout manager should handle a 
component that isn't visible. The modes are:*

*0 -Default. Means that invisible components will be handled exactly as if they were visible.*

*1 -The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0.*

*2 -The size of the component (if invisible) will be set to 0, 0 and the gaps will also be set to 0 around it.*

*3 -Invisible components will not participate in the layout at all and it will for instance not take up a grid cell.*

Your code will become:

```
DynamicString() {
    jp=new JPanel(sl);
    b1=new JButton("SHOW");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    jp.add(b1,"newline, w 100!, h 100!"); 

    b2=new JButton("Button 2");
    jp.add(b2,"w 100!, h 100!, hidemode 0"); // use whatever hidemode mode that's the more convenient for you
    b2.setVisible(false);

    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    jf.setVisible(true);

    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    b2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend using MigLayout. It is not part of the Java API, it might bring some licensing problems (it is GPL) for commercial Applications and if other people should participate on the project they have to get used to it first... I would recommend using Java API if it also gets the job done...

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that when you press the button more than once, you add the same button multiple times to the panel and the `SpringLayout` cannot handle it.

You can avoid this by removing `b1` before doing anything else in your `actionPerformed`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
      jp.remove(b2);  /* remove the button first! */
      sl.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,b2,10,SpringLayout.EAST,b1);
      jp.add(b2);
      jp.repaint();
      jp.validate();
}
```

This should not cause any problems the first time as removing a non-existent element has no effect!

Comment: tthis worked!!! but i could understand why i have to remove button b2 before adding it???As per the rule,any component is removed from its previous container if the component is added it another container.....so when i click Button b1 for 2nd time,the button b2 should be automatically removed from its container and then it should be added in the same container....

Comment: If it works, please mark the answer as correct. You don't have the button twice if you add it multiple times, but the `SpringLayout` cannot handle it correctly. I assume that is because the Constraint still belongs to the "old instance" of the button when you add it the second time and is not used for the "new instance", even though it is the same object.

Comment: ok...but when i clicked Button b1 for 1st time,shouldnt it give any error as it have to remove b2 which isnt in the container???

Comment: No, removing a non-existent element simply has no effect.

Comment: the above meathod is not working if replace Button b2 with a JLabel

Comment: For me it makes no difference! Are you sure you changed all references of the `JButton` to the `JLabel`? Especially in the constraint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99588/discussion-between-shadab-faiz-and-java-doe).